# The users can access to my admin route

Tags: php, cakephp

I'm trying to understand how ACL works . I got it and i have almost what i want. I have two groups : (group id : 1 for admin and group id : 2 for costumers) . The admins can have access for all of the controllers and view . The costumers can have access to the edit views and the view "view" in the User Controller .

My problem is that if the costumers (also the users not loged) write in their web browsers : http://www.myadress.com/admin, they can have access . I just don't understand why, i have to do something else because i add the route admin ?

I created a admin_index view in my controller Page .

My appController :

```
<?php

App::uses('Controller', 'Controller');

class AppController extends Controller {
    public $components = array(
        'Acl',
        'Auth' => array(
            'authorize' => array(
                'Actions' => array('actionPath' => 'controllers')
            )
        ),
        'Session'
    );

    public $helpers = array('Html', 'Form', 'Session');

    public function beforeFilter() {
    parent::beforeFilter();
        //Configure AuthComponent
        $this->Auth->loginAction = array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'login');
        $this->Auth->logoutRedirect = array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'login');
        $this->Auth->loginRedirect = array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'home');

        if(isset($this->request->params["prefix"]) && $this->request->params["prefix"] == "admin"){
            $this->layout = "admin";
        } else {
            $this->layout = "default";
        }
    }

}
```

My PagesController :

```
<?php
App::uses('AppController', 'Controller');

class PagesController extends AppController {

    public $uses = array();

 public function beforeFilter() {
    parent::beforeFilter();
    $this->Auth->allow();
}

    public function display() {
        $path = func_get_args();

        $count = count($path);
        if (!$count) {
            return $this->redirect('/');
        }
        $page = $subpage = $title_for_layout = null;

        if (!empty($path[0])) {
            $page = $path[0];
        }
        if (!empty($path[1])) {
            $subpage = $path[1];
        }
        if (!empty($path[$count - 1])) {
            $title_for_layout = Inflector::humanize($path[$count - 1]);
        }
        $this->set(compact('page', 'subpage', 'title_for_layout'));

        try {
            $this->render(implode('/', $path));
        } catch (MissingViewException $e) {
            if (Configure::read('debug')) {
                throw $e;
            }
            throw new NotFoundException();
        }
    }

    public function admin_index() {
        $title_for_layout = 'Dashboard';
        $this->set(compact('title_for_layout'));
    }

}
```

routes.php

```
 * Here, we are connecting '/' (base path) to controller called 'Pages',
 * its action called 'display', and we pass a param to select the view file
 * to use (in this case, /app/View/Pages/home.ctp)...
 */
    Router::connect('/', array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'display', 'home'));
/**
 * ...and connect the rest of 'Pages' controller's urls.
 */
    Router::connect('/pages/*', array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'display'));
    Router::connect('/admin', array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'index', 'admin' => true));
```

LabController (it's the controller i use for setting the acl parameters)

```
<?php

class LabController extends AppController {

public $uses = array('User', 'Group');

public function beforeFilter() {
    parent::beforeFilter();

    // Pour CakePHP 2.1 et supérieurs
    $this->Auth->allow();
}

public function setacl() {
    $group = $this->User->Group;
    // Autorise l'accès à tout pour les admins
    $group->id = 1;
    $this->Acl->allow($group, 'controllers');

    // Autorisation de l'édition du profil pour les clients
    $group->id = 2;
    $this->Acl->deny($group, 'controllers');
    $this->Acl->allow($group, 'controllers/users/edit');
    $this->Acl->allow($group, 'controllers/users/view');

    // Permet aux utilisateurs classiques de se déconnecter
    $this->Acl->allow($group, 'controllers/users/logout');

    // Nous ajoutons un exit pour éviter d'avoir un message d'erreur affreux "missing views" (manque une vue)
    echo "tout est ok";
    exit;
}
```

....
function build_acl after that ...

Answer (score 0):

You might check group_id in beforeRender() event . i.e after beforeFiler(). Logic should be like this

```
function beforeRender()
        {
            parent::beforeRender();

            if(AuthComponent::user('role') == 'admin' && AuthComponent::user('group_id') == 1)
            {
                $this->Auth->allow('view','add','edit','delete');
            }
            else
            {
                  // do something like redirect
            }
        }
```

P.S I didnt check code yet. Should be okay.

Comment: Thanks for your help, in the AppController i have to put this function ?

Comment: yes , AppController as all Controllers inherited from it.